# Way to access Renderable submesh(es) in ARCore/Sceneform?

Tags: arcore, sceneform

Using ARCore/Sceneform APIs, I need to access a specific submesh of a Renderable, but can't find the way to do It.

I wonder whether this functionality is implemented through RenderableDefinition, but the docs are'n very clear on this topic.

Any advice on this?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: if found a way please put it here

Comment: No advances at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You can access it using getMaterial(int subMeshIndex) method.

```
ModelRenderable modelRenderable = (ModelRenderable) transformableNode.getRenderable();
modelRenderable.getMaterial(4); //4 is the submesh index
```

Comment: Any way of doing it using names of the submeshes instead of index offsets?

Comment: I am not sure about that. Will have to check.

Comment: There is a method to get submesh name from the index. So we can create a hashmap of names to index and define it globally. Now, we can use the submesh name to get the specific submesh through the hasmap.

Comment: Please note that, under (last and archived version) Sceneform 1.16.0, submesh size is always return 0 (issue here), so is not possible to access a specific one,